# Como nomear vários dataframes de forma automática no Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Preciso de ajuda para automatizar um processo de nomeação de dataframes que estou aplicando. Importei 3 arquivos csv e apliquei o código abaixo, que funcionou sem problemas:

**Loja_1, Loja_2, Loja_3 = (pd.read_csv(cont) for cont in base)**

Consigo operar os diferentes df (Loja_1, Loja_2 e Loja_3) perfeitamente, ou seja a parte do código (pd.read_csv(cont) for cont in arquivos) está funcionando. Entretanto, desejo automatizar a geração dos nomes Loja_1 até Loja_n. Como está, tenho que nomeá-los manualmente, mas a quantidade de df pode muito grande, então desejo faze-lo automaticamente.

Alguém pode me ajudar com esta parte do código?

Grato

Comment: Porque não usas um dicionário? `{Loja_1: df1, Loja_2: df2, ...}`? basicamente seria qualquer coisa como `{'Loja_{}'.format(n): pd.read_csv(cont) for n, cont in enumerate(base, 1)`

Comment: Rodei o código - novo={'Loja_{}'.format(n): pd.read_csv(cont) for n, cont in enumerate(base, 1)}. Quando dei o comando type(novo), retornou dict (beleza). Mas ao executar o comando pd.DataFrame.from_dict(novo), retorna: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index.

Comment: Porque queres fazer isso? já tens os df no dict, e para a aceder a cada um deles basta `novo['Loja_1']` ou `novo['Loja_2']` ou `novo['Loja_3']` etc...

Comment: Eu precisava gerar um dataframe onde o nome das lojas aparecesse em uma coluna. Assim, poderia trabalhar com groupby. Resolvi o problema, lendo com Glob e depois executando dentro de um for read + append dentro de uma lista. Ao final, fiz um concat. 

arquivos = sorted(glob('Arquivos_Cliente/*.csv'))

df_intermediario = []
for arquivo in arquivos:
    df = pd.read_csv(arquivo)
    df_intermediario.append(df)
    
df_base = pd.concat(df_intermediario, ignore_index=True)

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in range(1, n): #sendo n o número de lojas+1
     loja ='Loja_'+str(i)
     print(loja)
```

Coloquei como print para você testar, mas é esse formato de string + contador que pode fazer essa tarefa por você :)

Comment: Até este pondo, eu consigo chega. Meu problema é linkar as variáveis geradas com o respectivo dataframe